# How to Allow tags in instance metadata using Terraform AWS Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'd like to enable/allow this AWS EC2 Instance Setting "**Access to tags in instance metadata**" using one of my Terraform's resources **[aws_launch_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_configuration)** OR **[aws_autoscaling_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group)**.

I have tried to use this argument **[metadata_options](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_configuration#metadata_options)** of **aws_launch_configuration** resource but it did not work.

In addition find this GitHub Issue [aws_launch_configuration add support for Instance Metadata Options #14621](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/14621)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did it error? Did the instances in your ASG cycle after applying?

Comment: Yes, the Terraform apply command successfully passed and a new EC2 instance launched but the Allow checkbox of "Access to tags in instance metadata" still not checked.

Comment: I see that the instance_metadata_tags is missing in aws_launch_configuration but exists in aws_launch_template